# Removendo o prefixo index.php no wampserver windows, é possível?

Tags: apache, htaccess, wamp

É possível retirar o prefixo `index.php` em meus projetos locais usando wampserver?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leo, você ganhou um negativo (não de mim) provavelmente porque falta detalhes na sua resposta. Sugiro que melhora a explicação.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters a pergunta está bem clara ao meu ver, retirar o ".php" da URL.

Comment: Pois é, pra mim também está clara, pois já tive o problema. Mas talvez não esteja clara para quem deu o negativo, ou para alguém que possa enfretar o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível.

Você precisa alterar o `.htaccess` e verificar se o `mod_rewrite` está ativo.

No htaccess você coloca assim:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Lembrando que, como você está usando o `wamp`, você provavelmente terá que habilitar o `mod_rewrite` do seu apache.

Para habilitar o mod_rewrite, utilize as instruções conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, creio que seja necessário também reiniciar o seu servidor wamp.

Comment: Poderia adicionar na resposta como ativar o mod_rewrite do apache utilizando o wamp, só como complemento. Mas se ele souber fazer isso penso que o problema fica resolvido.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes acho que dá sim. O único problema é que eu uso o ubuntu. Talvez posso fazer isso pelo virtualbox (quando chegar em casa hoje)

Comment: Muito obrigado, Wallace Maxters. Problema resolvido apenas ativando o rewrite_module